# Failed to load data source for config using Play-2.6 and Quill.io

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.6, quill.io

I'm currently getting an error when I try to run my Play app. It says `Failed to load data source` but then it looks like it is indeed loading the data source. I'm very new to Play and Scala and the rest of my team is also new, so apologies if this is a silly error or if I'm missing some code samples. Database `app-users` with owner `root` exists on my local and I don't believe `root` has a password (created using the `createuser` tool).

Any ideas on what could cause this? Or what I am missing?

Error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[IllegalStateException: Failed to load data source for config: 'Config(SimpleConfigObject({"dataSource":"org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource","database":"app-users","driver":"org.postgresql.Driver","host":"localhost","password":"","port":5432,"url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app-users","user":"root"}))']
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:186)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$3(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$24.onPush(Ops.scala:1191)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:512)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:475)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:371)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:584)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load data source for config: 'Config(SimpleConfigObject({"dataSource":"org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource","database":"app-users","driver":"org.postgresql.Driver","host":"localhost","password":"","port":5432,"url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app-users","user":"root"}))'
    at io.getquill.JdbcContextConfig.dataSource(JdbcContextConfig.scala:24)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:17)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:18)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:19)
    at db.db.package$DBContext.<init>(package.scala:6)
    at MyComponents.ctx$lzycompute(MyApplicationLoader.scala:19)
    at MyComponents.ctx(MyApplicationLoader.scala:19)
    at MyComponents.userService$lzycompute(MyApplicationLoader.scala:22)
    at MyComponents.userService(MyApplicationLoader.scala:22)
    at MyComponents.applicationController$lzycompute(MyApplicationLoader.scala:29)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:154)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:57)
    at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.<init>(HikariConfig.java:132)
    at io.getquill.JdbcContextConfig.dataSource(JdbcContextConfig.scala:21)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:17)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:18)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:19)
    at db.db.package$DBContext.<init>(package.scala:6)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:149)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:57)
    at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.<init>(HikariConfig.java:132)
    at io.getquill.JdbcContextConfig.dataSource(JdbcContextConfig.scala:21)
```

application.conf

```
play.db {
  config = "db"
  default = "default"
}

db.default {
  driver     = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  dataSource = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  url        = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app-users"
  user       = "root"
  user       = ${?DB_USER}
  host       = "localhost"
  host       = ${?DB_HOST}
  port       = 5432
  port       = ${?DB_PORT}
  password   = ""
  password   = ${?DB_PASSWORD}
  database   = "app-users"
}
```

db/package.scala

```
import io.getquill.{PostgresJdbcContext, SnakeCase}

package object db {
  class DBContext(config: String) extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase, config)

  trait Repository {
    val ctx: DBContext
  }
}
```

Using:

- Scala 2.12.4
- Quill 2.3.2
- Play 2.6.6
- Postgres JDBC Driver 42.2.1
- PostgreSQL 10.2

UPDATE:
Added a password of "root" to the root user and switched to using the same format as the [Quill docs](http://getquill.io/#contexts-sql-contexts-postgres-quill-jdbc), so now appliation.conf looks like this:

```
db.default {
    dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    dataSource.user = root
    dataSource.password = root
    dataSource.databaseName = app-users
    dataSource.portNumber = 5432
    dataSource.serverName = host
    connectionTimeout = 30000
}
```

But the error message is still basically the same:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[IllegalStateException: Failed to load data source for config: 'Config(SimpleConfigObject({"connectionTimeout":30000,"dataSource":{"databaseName":"app-users","password":"root","portNumber":5432,"serverName":"host","user":"root"},"dataSourceClassName":"org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"}))']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
db.default {
    dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    dataSource.user = root
    dataSource.password = root
    dataSource.databaseName = app-users
    dataSource.portNumber = 5432
    dataSource.serverName = localhost
    connectionTimeout = 30000
}
```

Basically, `localhost` instead of `host`. I'm guessing the first iteration didn't work because of the quotes.