# Conflict between Hikari, Quill, and Postgres in the conf file for Play 2.6

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, hikaricp, quill.io

I'm getting what seems to be a strange error when I run my Play app (which seems to be the story of my life right now). The other day, I ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033199/failed-to-load-data-source-for-config-using-play-2-6-and-quill-io/49052048#49052048), solved that, was able to run the evolutions and create the tables, and then ran into the following:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Property driver does not exist on target class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig`

Here is the relevant section from my current application.conf:

```
db.default {
    dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app-users?user=root&password=root"
    driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    username = root
    password = root
    databaseName = app-users
    portNumber = 5432
    serverName = localhost
    connectionTimeout = 30000
}
```

I did [some digging](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L485) and found that Hikari expects `driverClassName` (along with a few other differences). The [Hikari docs](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and the [Quill docs](http://getquill.io/#contexts-sql-contexts-postgres-quill-jdbc) say that something like this should be in the application.conf:

```
dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.user=root
dataSource.password=root
dataSource.databaseName=app-users
dataSource.portNumber=5432
dataSource.serverName=localhost
```

However, when I have that, the evolutions won't run. They will only run when I have it as I currently do. Since the evolutions are running, it seems like it is connecting to the db. So why would I get a message saying that it can't? Is there a way for me to have a separate db config for Hikari and Postgres/Quill?

Full error message:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[IllegalStateException: Failed to load data source for config: 'Config(SimpleConfigObject({"connectionTimeout":30000,"dataSourceClassName":"org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource","databaseName":"mack-users","driver":"org.postgresql.Driver","password":"root","portNumber":5432,"serverName":"localhost","url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mack-users?user=root&password=root","username":"root"}))']
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:186)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$3(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$24.onPush(Ops.scala:1191)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:512)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:475)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:371)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:584)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load data source for config: 'Config(SimpleConfigObject({"connectionTimeout":30000,"dataSourceClassName":"org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource","databaseName":"mack-users","driver":"org.postgresql.Driver","password":"root","portNumber":5432,"serverName":"localhost","url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mack-users?user=root&password=root","username":"root"}))'
    at io.getquill.JdbcContextConfig.dataSource(JdbcContextConfig.scala:24)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:17)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:18)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:19)
    at db.db.package$DBContext.<init>(package.scala:6)
    at MyComponents.ctx$lzycompute(MyApplicationLoader.scala:25)
    at MyComponents.ctx(MyApplicationLoader.scala:25)
    at MyComponents.userService$lzycompute(MyApplicationLoader.scala:28)
    at MyComponents.userService(MyApplicationLoader.scala:28)
    at MyComponents.applicationController$lzycompute(MyApplicationLoader.scala:35)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Property driver does not exist on target class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:131)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:57)
    at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.<init>(HikariConfig.java:132)
    at io.getquill.JdbcContextConfig.dataSource(JdbcContextConfig.scala:21)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:17)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:18)
    at io.getquill.PostgresJdbcContext.<init>(PostgresJdbcContext.scala:19)
    at db.db.package$DBContext.<init>(package.scala:6)
```

db/package.scala

```
import io.getquill.{PostgresJdbcContext, SnakeCase}

package object db {
  class DBContext(config: String) extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase, config)

  trait Repository {
    val ctx: DBContext
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what could cause this? Or what I am missing?

Using:

- Scala 2.12.4
- Quill 2.3.2
- Play 2.6.6
- Postgres JDBC Driver 42.2.1
- PostgreSQL 10.2

Error message when I put what Quill/Hikari expect:

```
! @776d39n6c - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:156)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:990)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1$adapted(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:86)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:75)
    at play.api.db.DBComponents.dbApi(DBModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.DBComponents.dbApi$(DBModule.scala:49)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:156)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:990)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:63)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$connect$1$adapted(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:997)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConfig.toHikariConfig(HikariCPModule.scala:136)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.$anonfun$create$1(HikariCPModule.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:47)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
```

Comment: Do you get any error when you put what quill wants in `application.conf` or do evolutions just not run at all?  Also how do you create your jdbc context?  We use something like `@Singleton
class DefaultDbContext extends PostgresJdbcContext[SnakeCase](SnakeCase, "ctx")` which means we prefix every config param with `ctx`, so `ctx.dataSourceClassName` - not sure but maybe that could resolve any conflicts.

Comment: @MattFowler I do get a different error when I put what Quill wants in `application.conf` and evolutions don't run. I'll update the question with that error message and the jdbc context.

Comment: Actually from docs I take that Quill expects `application.properties` (with Java Properties format) and Play (which I guess uses Slick) needs `application.conf` with HOCON format. I guess, that if you provided both files, it could work - that would be a nice fallback option before figuring out how to use one config for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Hikari and Play don't use quite the same naming conventions for setting up their data source, for instance Quill expects a bare `dataSourceClassName` but Play wants it in a format like `db.default.dataSourceClassName`.  As far as I can tell there is no way to rework your config so that it will satisfy both of them and you may not want to for the following reason:

Play actually uses Hikari as it's pooling data source, so when you create a db via `db.default` you're actually already creating a pooled data source.  When you call `PostgresJdbcContext` with a bare config you're actually asking Quill to create a totally separate connection pool. Not sure if this is what you want but I'd assume you'd want only one connection pool.

Quill actually exposes a constructor that takes in a `DataSource`, so what you can do is use the `Database` that Play has created and just pass it in directly to Quill:

```
import io.getquill.{PostgresJdbcContext, SnakeCase}
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import play.api.db.Database

package object db {
    class DBContext(db: Database) extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase, db.dataSource.asInstanceOf[HikariDataSource])
}
```

This should solve your problem and will only create one connection pool. You can get at a `Database` object via dependency injection.

You have to do an ugly `asInstanceOf` here because the `PostgresJdbcContext` requires the `dataSource` to implement `Closeable`, which the bare `DataSource` class does not implement.  I've ran into a similar issue and haven't found a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! One more question though: if I make the updates like you suggest, how would I go about initializing the DBContext later in the code? `val ctx = new DBContext(???)`

Comment: @jmkoni I would consider letting dependency injection take care of things for you. If you made a class like this: `@Singleton
class DBContext @Inject()(db: Database)
  extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase, db.dataSource.asInstanceOf[HikariDataSource])` Then in any controller you need a DBContext you can just do: `@Singleton
class MyController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents,
                                 dbContext: DBContext)` and you don't ever need to create a DBContext directly yourself.